# Regex failing to search a string

Tags: python

I am trying to do a regex search for `Location:` and get its location as follows,can anyone help to figure out why it doesn't print the location,expected output is shown below?

```
output = """
Build:          BOOT.FAN.1.2-00179-M1234LAB-1
Location:       \\location\builds678\INTEGRATION\BOOT.FAN.1.2-00179-M1234LAB-1
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved  [Approved for Testing]
BuildDate:      07/14/2016 17:54:54
"""
match=re.search(r'Location:\s*(\w*)',output)
print match.group(1)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
\\location\builds678\INTEGRATION\BOOT.FAN.1.2-00179-M1234LAB-1
```

Comment: '\\' is not matched by `\w`

Comment: how to match `\\` along with a combination of everything(numbers,alphabets,special characters)

Comment: re.search(r'Location:\s*(.*)',output).group(1)

Comment: You can also use `.` to match any character but the newline.  By specifying the `re.DOTALL` flag you can also match newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string appears to contain special characters such as backspace (`\b`). You probably need to escape the backslashes, or use a raw string:

```
output = r"""
Build:          BOOT.FAN.1.2-00179-M1234LAB-1
Location:       \\location\builds678\INTEGRATION\BOOT.FAN.1.2-00179-M1234LAB-1
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved  [Approved for Testing]
BuildDate:      07/14/2016 17:54:54
"""
```

Also there are a few other characters in the target string that will not be matched by just `\w`: `\`, `.` and `-` as per your example, possibly more. Try this pattern:

```
match = re.search(r'Location:\s+([\w\\\.-]+)',output)
print match.group(1)
```

Also you could simply match all characters to the end of the line:

```
match = re.search(r'Location:\s+(.+)',output)
print match.group(1)
```